# I'm Jelly of Python (Cops)

Tags: code-golf, cops-and-robbers, python, jelly

<sup>[What does "jelly" mean in the title?](https://www.cyberdefinitions.com/definitions/JELLY.html). [Robber's thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/222478/66833)</sup>

Jelly has an "Evaluate the argument as Python 3" atom, `ŒV` which takes a string as an argument as evaluates that string as Python 3 code: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5yCosy8Eg0lD6BAvo5CeH5RToqikuajhrlHJ4X9/w8A).

It also has compressed strings, delimited with `“...»` that can compress any string containing printable ASCII (plus newlines), which can reduce the size of such programs. For example, a [Hello, World!](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9qZWxsef//4oCcwqThuZnhuovIr8K9xKA8csW7wqPGpOG4pE/Cu8WSVv//) program using `ŒV`

Now, this is much longer that Jelly's normal `Hello, World!` program, by 9 bytes. But is this always the case?

Cops, you are to choose an [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge; write a Python solution to this challenge; compress that solution into Jelly and submit that as your answer.

The challenge you choose must meet these criteria:

- It is open
- It it unlocked
- It has a net score of 5 or more
- Its winning criteria is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) and *only* [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)
- All languages are open to compete in it (so no [python](/questions/tagged/python)-only challenges etc.)
- It is not a [tips](/questions/tagged/tips) question
- It was posted before the 28th of March, 2021

[This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=is%3aq%20%5bcode-golf%5d%20-%5btips%5d%20closed%3a0%20locked%3a0%20score%3a5..%20created%3a..2021-03-28) is a search query that should return (mostly) valid challenges. There's no way to filter challenges on the 4th and 5th criteria, so double check the challenges you choose from this search.

Your answer should contain:

- A piece of Jelly code in the format `“...»ŒV`, where the `...` may be any string of characters from [Jelly's code page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page), aside from `“”‘’«»`
- A link to the challenge you solved
- The length of your "Python to Jelly" code, in bytes

Note that your program must follow any and all rules stated in the challenge you solve, including builtin bans, strict I/O formats and whatever else. To fully cover all edge cases: **Your program must be able to be posted as a valid answer to the challenge**. The only exception to this rule is that if the challenge scores in characters, you should instead score in bytes.

Jelly currently is written in Python 3.7.4 ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5zM3IL8ohKF4spi64KizLwSDSBLryy1qDgzP0/zUcPco5PC/v8HAA), the same version that TIO's [Python 3](https://tio.run/#python3) uses), so your program must work in that version of Python.

You may not edit the rules of the challenge you've chosen. You may not simply compress an existing Python answer to the challenge and submit that as your own work. However, you are allowed to attempt to modify existing users' code in order to improve your score, so long as you provide proper attribution to the original answerer. [Alternative wording](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57463139#57463139).

Your answer is "cracked" if a Robber finds a Jelly program shorter than your "Python to Jelly" program, that completes the same task. Note that a Robber's crack is valid even if it's of the same form (compressed Python eval'ed by Jelly), so long as it's shorter.

Your answer is "safe" if it is uncracked after 2 weeks. You must mark your answer as safe to be considered so. The shortest safe answer, in bytes, wins

[This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/151721) is, as far as we know, the most optimal Jelly compressor which might help you

### Example submission

```
# 17 bytes, solves https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world

    “¤ṙẋȯ½Ġ<rŻ£ƤḤO»ŒV

[Try it online!][TIO-kmrxghbo]

[TIO-kmrxghbo]: https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9qZWxsef//4oCcwqThuZnhuovIr8K9xKA8csW7wqPGpOG4pE/Cu8WSVv// "Jelly – Try It Online"
```

Comment: In Jelly, is there any way to pass arguments to the python program?

Comment: @Ausername The same way you would access arguments in a normal Python program: `input()` still works, as does `import sys;sys.argv`

Comment: Must cops have a crack?

Comment: @JonathanAllan No. I'd consider this more of a "Python + compression vs Jelly golfing competition", rather than a typical CnR, I just chose that competition type because it fits best. There might be a few questions on the site that are downright impossible in Jelly but doable in Python, but I'm not sure that's the case, so I think every Cop answer should be doable in Jelly, but not necessarily in a shorter way

Comment: I've got little experience with Jelly, but the compressor linked in the question links to [this other compressor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/70916/tips-for-golfing-in-jelly/151721#151721) which claims to be optimal and seems much easier to use

Comment: I suspect this challenge is just going to result in cops picking challenges that python has builtins for, such as file I/O, sockets, hashing etc.

Comment: @Leo That's the same compressor as the one in the question

Comment: Uh... I must have scrolled the page involuntarily when I clicked on that link last time, and ended up on a different string compressor on the same page... Sorry ^^"

Comment: You may want to limit the `...` to Jelly's base 250 characters to prevent Jelly injection.

Comment: @Sisyphus You're probably right. Then it comes down to golfing the python...

Comment: Or finding better compression. Neither of which are very interesting.

Answer (score 9):

## 21 bytes, solves [Shortest code to throw SIGILL](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/100532) (safe)

```
“A{gœỴ¹⁻ėe⁾÷ỤḞḂ4ḷ$»ŒV
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATQAy/9qZWxsef//4oCcQXtnxZPhu7TCueKBu8SXZeKBvsO34buk4bie4biCNOG4tyTCu8WSVv//)

This decompresses to the following Python 3 code (which is 22 bytes long, only one byte longer than the compressed version):

```python
import os
os.kill(0,4)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRCG/mCu/WC87MydHw0DHRPP/fwA)

The basic idea is to pick a task that's completely out of scope for Jelly; in this case, we're interacting with the OS, something that Jelly doesn't have builtins for (short of `ŒV`). So this probably isn't solvable in Jelly without shelling out to Python, and hopefully isn't solvable any more tersely than this.

(In case you're wondering how it works: 4 is the signal number for SIGILL, and `os.kill` appears to just copy its arguments to the `kill(2)` system call literally. 0 means "send this signal to every process in my process group", which if the program is run from a shell, will raise a SIGILL in the Python/Jelly program and nothing else. On TIO, the program is being run from TIO's runner, so the SIGILL happens in the runner rather than in the program itself, but there's still a SIGILL being raised.)

Answer (score 7):

## 25 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page), solves [We had a question once which only failed on Sundays](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/152578/53748) - [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222490/53748) (Razetime)

```
“ÇṄṚ,Ḣ¢;Xv^wME ṖƘżẓ⁸9!»ŒV
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATYAyf9qZWxsef//4oCcw4fhuYThuZos4biiwqI7WHZed01FIOG5lsaYxbzhupPigbg5IcK7xZJW//8)**

The compressed code is heavily based on [Mr XCoder's submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/152579/53748):

```python
exit('Su'in time.ctime()<_)
```

Notes:

- There's no need to `import time` since Jelly's interpreter does that, but not much is exposed, just sleeping and simple time formating (and no other date or time functionality exists).
- Something is required to do both of these, I chose `exit`:

  - not return `False` on non-Sundays (since a bool is not `jellify`-able)
  - not print to STDOUT on non-Sundays

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222490/80214) (I think)

Comment: Ah, nice use of `X`!

Answer (score 5):

## 132 bytes, solves [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/109248/mathematics-is-fact-programming-is-not) - Non-competing

```
“ßẏƊḢ⁵'ĠȦṫ-ỵḲ²ƘçẠaðṁ¹ĠẊḊƝ;ɠ)ṭKpƭȯVsRDỤ⁵ṾḶĿṇƈ>bỴøỴ⁻Ñy1®ḶṪ\ḷ⁶ḋẇƊ⁾L⁼ṀHṃYṘZ1ẏ1ʋḤFTʠzɱĊȦṁƈṠ!ỌẎḌʂ&B?o#Ṗ³⁻Eḋ4ỤṙṃɲɼĖṬƘmẏġ^wp=ạİQƊ)Ḅı/ẉNẊ`»ŒV
```

I don't really know Python, so I used Javascript, executed by Python, executed by Jelly. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY9RKwRRGIZ/y6RoL8SUO6GEFCnSFkkoN1rZcqF1tQe1a3YjLrZVtLPaKCy7w67znbOtmjlOO/Mv3vkj47j5bt63532@g/1MJpckcf4@qEFcawf8MWadEeUOnkCvo5AdcM/3dDV4hnB3gxaI@aRcCFN19MNk6KZAzaWsbg4@0sdrc5ANAwD1wbvqB1TQxek9yK@AmxMzGdzkbP/dhKCXLfDvmHXBSxAF7cSsvxyzHii/CDrfAFU3bSNlRyXwxsJ65J6GbeX8izFdBLkWZBniCrwcnQ3PzhwNgSr@p9mYN8QJIwK6M6DQC3uqAnrT1UODU/Xtk@wURF21VrWTAr9Q7TGIyxXz0o4vf2/TSWKNW9Yf)

The Python code:

```python
import os
os.system("node -e \"console.log((x=>+x.replace(/(.*)(0|1)(.*)/,(m,a,b,c)=>(((c?1:b)*2-1)*((-1)**a.length)+1)/2))(process.argv[1]))\" "+ input())
```

And finally the Javascript:

```javascript
console.log((x=>+x.replace(/(.*)(0|1)(.*)/,(m,a,b,c)=>(((c?1:b)*2-1)*((-1)**a.length)+1)/2))(process.argv[1]))
```

I expect this to be very easy to beat, but I wanted to have a go.

Comment: VeMḂ$, apparently.

Comment: @rak1507 See my comment at the end.

Comment: pro tip: don't submit answers to challenges that already have jelly answers lol

Comment: I should've looked. Oh well.

Comment: I think “2ẇHɓḤQṣuøȤ⁵ÇJÐD°ÞṣȯẎḍ.®rȥLẠ\O/²ṭ⁽ỵẇẇ€¬$~ŻrİȯɼẸ2ṃƙṗṙƙḊƁ~§BaO[İdʠ½ġ⁺\>ƇżḶẓ⁵¡nḋḅ)ẓ_³oḂ9 ¤ḲẊ(ȷḄ¢ƙȥʠoⱮṖ⁽ɱḲⱮnßẋȷBṙȤṾƘ⁹ḟẠṙGĊĖæÞ£ẓÆ<ð⁸» works for the compression (slightly shorter) as well, although I haven't tested it

Comment: Yup that works - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DY5PSwJRFMW/SkKL2lS4C6KFBEUE0qZNQgS1CVEQWrSRxv4MjBSRYA2EjTnWxnQ0zPue2uK@meGN3@K@LzJdOHA4vwvn3IvzYvEqTc31W5akvZc0CPxDEp1LBdo31ljZ@@ppBwPVYqgHJB8JHtawX9HdA5JeIb@OIxLfxprTdMwNLFPrYW@5Gk0rYaAHyYwkZEncxC6JFxIuOzixVcWv3Gn@OAzOFh7Ow7axZGE7tqMZwS/JBk9ju0RQJ7hb5XyCP2WC2uYS@gQjks6KnhDc4kfs6u7CK5thn0ST30iGfOdUUu8k63qS40ntk/iLX40lCJh6jHZDJ2yqT9XCDrer@y0VGAtwGj0fpelGJvMP "Jelly – Try It Online")

Comment: Wait, did [I crack this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109345/53748) without even posting in the robber's thread?!

Comment: @JonathanAllan Sorry, forgot to check if a Jelly answer already existed.