# I'm Jelly of Python (Robbers)

Tags: code-golf, cops-and-robbers, python, jelly

<sup>[What does "jelly" mean in the title?](https://www.cyberdefinitions.com/definitions/JELLY.html). [Cop's thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/222477/66833)</sup>

Robbers, you are to choose an uncracked Cop answer, and attempt to find a Jelly program which is:

- shorter than the Cop's answer
- solves the linked challenge, according to the rules of the challenge

So long as these two bullet points are met, your answer cracks the Cop's.

The user with the most cracks wins.

### Example submission

```
# 8 bytes, cracks [ChartZ Belatedly's answer](<link to answer>)

    “3ḅaė;œ»

[Try it online!][TIO-kmrxlphk]

[TIO-kmrxlphk]: https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9RwxzjhztaE49Mtz46@dDu//8B "Jelly – Try It Online"
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 21 bytes, cracks [Jonathan Allan's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222489/80214)

```
“¡ẉḟUHġ[4A»ŒVw⁾SuNXṛ⁸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS4A0f9qZWxsef//4oCcwqHhuonhuJ9VSMShWzRBwrvFklZ34oG@U3VOWOG5m@KBuP//)

Takes the return value of `time.ctime()`, finds `Su` in it, and negates the value. On a Sunday, this passes -1 to `X` (random number function), causing an error. Otherwise it passes 0 to `X`, not erroring. then final return value is forced to be the empty string `⁸`, so it will print nothing.